# Getting out of bounds error

Tags: java

so I'm testing out this piece of code, and when I read a file, the output when being printed halts and I get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at WordLengths.countWordLengthsWithIsLettermethod(WordLengths.java:126)
    at WordLengths.testWordLengths(WordLengths.java:152)`.
I'm wondering if somewhere I inadvertently added a limit to how many results I get, otherwise I can't think of what could be wrong.

This is the bit that's causing trouble (`max = freqs[i];`):

```
     public int maxIndex(int[] freqs) {
        int max = freqs[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < freqs.length; i++) {
            if (freqs[i] > max) {
                max = freqs[i];

            }
        } 
        System.out.println("max number of words of certain lengths: "+max);
        return freqs[max];

        //return max;
    }
```

Here's the whole code with the problem area included:

```
import edu.duke.FileResource;

public class WordLengths {


    public void countWordLengths(FileResource resource, int[] counts) {
        String abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        for (String word : resource.words()) {
            String trim = word.trim();
            int wordSize = trim.length();
            //System.out.println("word" + "\t" + trim);
            int lastInd = trim.length()-1;
            //System.out.println("lastIndexOf word" + "\t" + lastInd);
            //abc.contains(trim.charAt(lastInd));
            char firstChar = trim.charAt(0);
            char endChar = trim.charAt(trim.length()-1);
            //System.out.println("firstChar" + "\t" + firstChar + "\t" + "endChar" + "\t" + endChar);
            int idx = abc.indexOf(firstChar);
            int idx_e = abc.indexOf(endChar);
            int edx_sum = idx + idx_e;
            //System.out.println("indexes abc" + "\t" + edx_sum);
            //int idx_s = small.indexOf(firstChar);
            //int idx_s_e = small.indexOf(endChar);
            //int edx_s_sum = idx_s + idx_s_e;
            //System.out.println("indexes small" + "\t" + edx_s_sum);
            //System.out.println("indexes" + "\t" + idx + "\t" + idx_e + "\t" + idx_s + "\t" + idx_s_e);
            //System.out.println("indexes" + "\t" + idx + "\t" + idx_e + "\t");

            if (idx == -1 && idx_e == -1) {
                wordSize -= 2;
            } else 
            if (idx == -1 || idx_e == -1) {
                wordSize -= 1;
            }
            if(wordSize>=counts.length) {
               counts[counts.length-1] += 1; 
            } else
            //right algorithm
            if( counts[wordSize] != 0) {
                counts[wordSize] += 1;

            } else {
                counts[wordSize] = 1;
            }



        }

        //test
            /*for(int i : counts) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }*/
    }
    /**
     * the method countWordLengths(FileResource resource, int[] counts) with isLetter method
     * 
     * @param resource
     * @param counts 
     */
    public void countWordLengthsWithIsLettermethod(FileResource resource, int[] counts) {
        for (String word : resource.words()) {
            String trim = word.trim();
            int wordSize = trim.length();
            char firstChar = trim.charAt(0);
            char endChar = trim.charAt(trim.length()-1);
            if (!Character.isLetter(firstChar) && !Character.isLetter(endChar)) {
                wordSize -= 2;
            } else 
            if (!Character.isLetter(firstChar) || !Character.isLetter(endChar)) {
                wordSize -= 1;
            }
            if(wordSize>=counts.length) {
               counts[counts.length-1] += 1; 
            } else
            //right algorithm
            if( wordSize> 0 && counts[wordSize] != 0  ) {
                counts[wordSize] += 1;

            } else if ( wordSize> 0) {
                counts[wordSize] = 1;

            }
             System.out.println(counts[wordSize] + " words with length " + wordSize + ": " + word);
        }

        //test
            /*for(int i : counts) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }*/
    }
     public int maxIndex(int[] freqs) {
        int max = freqs[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < freqs.length; i++) {
            if (freqs[i] > max) {
                max = freqs[i];

            }
        } 
        System.out.println("max number of words of certain lengths: "+max);
        return freqs[max];

        //return max;
    }
         public void testWordLengths() {
        WordLengths wl = new WordLengths();
        FileResource fr = new FileResource();
        int counts[] = new int[100];
        //wl.countWordLengths(fr, counts);
        wl.countWordLengthsWithIsLettermethod(fr, counts);
        wl.maxIndex(counts);
    }
}
```

Comment: go on, tell us which is line `WordLengths.java:126`.

Comment: Please post the code where the error is directed at.

Comment: I'm not sure where it's directed at. Could `WordLengths.java:126` mean it's on the 126th line?

Comment: Yes that is what it means.  But we do not know what is line 126

Comment: posted the location of the error

Answer (score 0):

What do think would happen if the word was empty (or just filled with blanks)

```
String trim = word.trim();
int wordSize = trim.length();
char firstChar = trim.charAt(0);
char endChar = trim.charAt(trim.length()-1);
```

Comment: I'm not sure, is this the bit that's causing the error?